# Como formatar uma tabela (data.frame) com qualidade de publicação em pdf (latex) no R?

Tags: r, pdf, data.frame, latex, tabela-html

Suponha a seguinte tabela:

```r
tabela <- structure(list(Sexo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Homem", 
"Mulher"), class = "factor"), Grupo = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Média = c(0.2655086631421, 
0.37212389963679, -0.835628612410047, 1.59528080213779), Var = c(0.329507771815361, 
0.820468384118015, 0.572853363351896, 0.908207789994776)), .Names = c("Sexo", 
"Grupo", "Média", "Var"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

tabela
    Sexo Grupo      Média        Var
1  Homem     A  0.2655087  0.3295078
2  Homem     B  0.3721239  0.8204684
3 Mulher     A -0.8356286  0.5728534
4 Mulher     B  1.5952808  0.9082078
```

Como deixá-la em formato de publicação, para um arquivo em `pdf` (usando `latex` por exemplo)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pode também usar o pacote `stargazer`

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(tabela, summary=FALSE)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8):

Um pacote que eu acho fantástico é o `tables`. Ele é bem flexível. Por exemplo, arrumando a `tabela` de três formas diferentes:

```
library(tables)
tabela1 <- tabular(~(Sexo)*Heading()*Grupo*Heading()*identity*(Média+Var), data=tabela)
tabela2 <- tabular((Sexo)~(Grupo)*Heading()*identity*(Média+Var), data=tabela)
tabela3 <- tabular(Sexo*Grupo~Heading()*identity*(Média+Var), data=tabela)
```

Para gerar o código `latex`:

```
latex(tabela1)
latex(tabela2)
latex(tabela3)
```

Resultados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o pacote `xtable`. Primeiro, é necessário baixar o pacote. No R, entre com o seguinte comando:

```r
install.packages("xtable")
```

Depois de instalado, carregue-o:

```
library("xtable")
```

Coloque a sua `tabela` no formato `data.frame` e aplique o comando:

```
xtable(tabela)
```